# DateTime format needed chnages as expected

Tags: java, date, datetime, format

I want to display time as `"02 Sep 2020 at 12:24 AM"` (mind the **at** between date and time).

The current format I am using is `"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm aaa"`,
which displays time as `"28 Aug 2020 11:32 AM"`.

How can I put an **at** before the time?

Answer (score 3):

You can add string literals to a date format by surrounding them with single quotes (`'`):

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy 'at' hh:mm aaa");
// Here -------------------------------------------------^--^

String formatted = sdf.format(myDateVariable);
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @OleV.V. on Android it is still difficult to use `java.time`, when min version of android 8 is required

Comment: @Vlad The question wasn’t about Android. For older Android you may use java.time either through [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or through [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). Still, if the answer said *here’s an answer for older Android*, it would be more helpful and have a smaller risk of leading someone else astray.

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap the word in single quotes.

```
"dd MMM yyyy 'at' hh:mm aaa"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) for this, you can define a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` to parse a `String`, use it to parse the `String` to a `java.time.LocalDateTime` and define & use another `DateTimeFormatter` that includes the `at` escaping it in the pattern by enclosing it in single-quotes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateTime = "02 Sep 2020 12:24 AM";
    DateTimeFormatter parserDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu hh:mm a",
                                                                Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateTimeFormatter outputDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu 'at' hh:mm a",
                                                                Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, parserDtf);
    System.out.println(ldt.format(outputDtf));
}
```

This code produces the output

```
02 Sep 2020 at 12:24 AM
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use the newer Time API or the old Date API for this. The question is about the `at` in the formatted date string, and the solution of using single-quoted `'at'` is the same for both. Obscuring the relevant part of the answer by preaching the new API is counter-productive. I'm not down-voting, because nothing here is wrong, but I'm not up-voting either, because of the unnecessary preaching that is *immaterial* to the question.

Comment: @Andreas OK, I rephrased the beginning a little to make it less *preaching*. I still feel like telling OPs who use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` about `java.time` is not totally unnecessary. I admit, they might know about it and use the outdated API for reasons, but in many cases they just don't know `java.time`.

Comment: Where in the question do you see any mention of `SimpleDateFormat`? You begin preaching, but the question applies equally to both APIs. How do you know OP isn't already using the Time API? Please control your zealousness when entirely unwarranted.

Comment: @Andreas I don't know it, neither was it mentioned, nor tagged. I just saw answers provided using `SimpleDateFormat`, found no comment stating *... but I am using `java.time`...* and that made me *preach* a solution in `java.time`.

Comment: You found no comment from OP because OP is likely **offline** and haven't seen any of the answers using `SimpleDateFormat`. You're making conclusion out of thin air. At this time, there is only one comment from OP *anywhere*, which was left 3 minutes after the question was posted, and the answer with the comment didn't mention `SimpleDateFormat` *at the time* (see answer history).

Comment: @Andreas I hope to find any response when OP gets online again and maybe posts a comment, edits the question or accepts one of the answers. Might take a while, could never happen, we'll or I'll see. Could be a wrong conclusion, but that's not sure so far.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, because the answer of single-quoting the `at` word applies equally to both APIs, making [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63737917/5221149) the **best** of them all. Short and to the point, with unnecessary extra code obfuscating the relevant part. Support clear concise answers and up-vote it. I sure have.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss z"); 
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: Can u  pls sahre the sample

Comment: What language is that supposed to be? What is `Convert`, what is `ToString`?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

Comment: Sorry, im currently using c#. But i shared the code above in java.

Comment: Then you should replace the answer content with that comment, C# answers are useless here.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.